# Apache not writable 777 folder fedora 30

Tags: apache, fedora, permission-denied

This probably a silly problem, but I can't get apache to write into my project folder `/var/www/html/myproject`. Below is the folder permission :

```
drwxr-xr-x.  9 shira  shira   4096 Nov  9 10:15 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    4096 Oct  3 15:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 14 shira  shira   4096 Jan 16  2019 application
drwxr-xr-x. 10 shira  shira   4096 Oct  7 15:50 assets
drwxr-xr-x.  2 shira  shira   4096 Aug  1 15:49 css
-rw-r--r--.  1 shira  shira    177 Nov 23  2017 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--.  1 shira  shira  10255 Jan 16  2019 index.php
drwxr-xr-x.  3 shira  shira   4096 Aug  1 15:49 js
drwxr-xr-x.  8 shira  shira   4096 Jan 16  2019 system
drwxrwxr-x.  3 apache apache  4096 Aug  9 15:10 upload
drwxr-xr-x. 14 shira  shira   4096 Jan 16  2019 user_guide
```

Notice that upload folder already 775 with folder owner already apache, but codeigniter still return `The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable`. Apache should be running apache:apache as defined in httpd.conf. I already tried change to 777, but still return same error.

Comment: Is selinux enabled? What does running (as root) `getenforce` report?

Comment: @larsks Yes, selinux is enabled.

Comment: Sounds like it might be your selinux policy denying the write access. What is the output of `audit2allow -a`? (You might need to install it first, `yum install /usr/bin/audit2allow`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check httpd / apache to have write access on the file/folder which blocked by SELINUX or not...

You can check with `ls -Z /var/www/html/myproject/`

Dont give permision 777 because this is bad practive. You can fix with

```
# Fixing file permissions, recursive
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

# Fixing directory permissions, recursive
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

back to the main issue, You need to give (restore) default SELinux context and allow write only to specific folder:

```
sudo restorecon /var/www/html/myproject/upload -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/myproject/upload -R
```